TV-Series with outer-space girl being able to turn into flying sphere of light
This series was aired on a kids channel (can't remember which) when I was younger. I think it is from the US and probably 1990s.
It was about a brown or black haired teenage girl who came from outer-space and could turn into a flying sphere of light. Episodes would center around her having troubles at school and also about some evil outer-space man that followed her to Earth and was trying to catch her.
I remember her having a boy as a friend from school, who knew about her being "different".
I also remember that in one episode the evil man actually captured the girl and put her into a big cage. That's all I can come up with...
Edit: Some other things came to me, but they could be wrong. Maybe they ring a bell for someone:

It could be that the girl could shape-shift and not just turn into a sphere of light.
The evil man had a company on Earth hiding some bad stuff going on there. The girl would investigate and try to prove that. I think this is how she got captured in one of the episodes.


It sounds like The Secret World of Alex Mack to me (intro here). 
BUT Alex Mack was not an alien, she got her powers from chemical GC-161 from nearby chemical plant, so I might be wrong. 
Other than that, what you described immediately brought this show to me, and it fits most of the other criteria:

US show
aired from 1994 on Nickelodeon
one of her powers is the shapeshifting (but to liquid metal form, not light sphere)
she has a friend named Ray who knows about her and goes to school with her
she was always trying to investigate more about the chemical plant/the chemical GC-161, and at the same time trying to avoid being caught by the chief of security (the evil man)


This must be it. Thanks a lot!
